# Rebase already merged branch on top of master

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I got the following problem. I have two  Git branches (First: Commits E, C, B and Second: Commit D) as seen on the picture beeing forked from and merged into the master branch (F and A)

[image: Git Tree]

I would like to put D at the top of A and remove it from the place it is currently located. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: If it’s just one commit you can use cherry pick instead

Comment: I thought so too, but I guess that will not remove the erroneous commit, doesn't it? The thing is I want to move not to copy.

Comment: B and C depends on D. If you want to "remove" D you will also need to "remove" C and B as well.

Comment: *Removing* a commit, i.e. changing the history of already commited and merged branches, especially if they're named `master`, is potentially very dangerous. If anyone else already pulled and is working on top, things get really messy. You might be better of just leaving the commit where it is and fix it with another commit.

Comment: @kowsky Yes I know. Luckily the only other person working on that repository sits right next to me. ;)

Comment: Sitting next to each other is by no means a safeguard against a git merge hell. :)

Comment: @ali Wait, is `C` only the merge commit from `D`?

Comment: Yes it is. I know I should not cherry-pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to reset master to `F`, reset `yellow` branch to `E`, cherry-pick `C` and `B` on `yellow` branch, merge `yellow` into `master` and finally cherry-pick `D`.

You should create a `backup` branch in the state of your current `master` before touching anything, to be able to reset to the current state if anything goes wrong, and to have easy access to the commit IDs you need to cherry-pick. The command sequence would be something like this:

```
#on master branch, with no unstaged or uncommited changes:
git branch backup
git reset --hard F
git checkout yellow
git reset --hard E
git cherry-pick C
git cherry-pick B

#merge yellow branch into master, however you usually do that

git checkout master
git cherry-pick D
```

Warning: not tested.

As I said in my comment, this will mess things up badly if anyone is already working on top of the old master.

EDIT: If `C` is the merge commit from `D` to `yellow`, it should oviously not be cherry-picked and can be ignored.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it later as soon as I am back at that project and give you a checkmark if it works. Looks promising.

Comment: Works like a charm. :D Thanks you.